# Scheme contract not violated

Tags: scheme, racket, contract

First, I apologize for the beginner question.  I am an experienced developer, but new to Scheme.  I have created a contract requiring a positive integer, but when I provide a real number, the contract is not violated:

```
(define/contract (listofOne n)
  (-> (and integer? positive?) (listof integer?))
  (cond
    ((= n 0) '())
    (else (cons 1 (listofOne (- n 1))))))

(listofOne 12.5)
```

I expected the contract to be violated, but instead I got an infinite loop and a buffer overflow.  Why did the contract remain unviolated?  The first query in my predicate was `integer?`, so I don't see how the contract could have returned true with an input of `12.5`.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, I am not looking for a way to make the contract violate.  I already know that I can use and/c, and (thanks to @soegaard) that I can reverse `positive?` and `integer?` to get it to violate.  What I'm looking for at this point is to understand what is going on here.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE

I totally missed that you used `and` and not `and/c` in your example.
Try this:

```
#lang racket
(define/contract (listofOne n)
  (-> (and/c integer? positive?) (listof integer?))
  (cond
    ((= n 0) '())
    (else (cons 1 (listofOne (- n 1))))))

(listofOne 12.5)
```

Result:

```
listofOne: contract violation
  expected: integer?
  given: 12.5
  in: an and/c case of
      the 1st argument of
      (->
       (and/c integer? positive?)
       (listof integer?))
  contract from: (function listofOne)
  blaming: anonymous-module
   (assuming the contract is correct)
  at: unsaved-editor:2.18
```

SECOND UPDATE

Here is an explanation of `and`.

The form

```
(and c1 c2)
```

means:

```
1. Evaluate `c1` giving a value `v`
2. If the value `v1` is false, 
   then the result of the `and`-expression is false.
   (note that `c2` is not evaluated)
3. If the value `v1` is non-false, 
   then evaluate the expression `c2` giving a value `v2`.
4. The result of the and-expressions is v2.
```

Note: If c1 evaluates to true, then `(and c1 c2)` gives the same result as `c2`.
This means in particular that if `c1` is a contract (which is a non-false value)
then `(and c1 c2)` gives the same result as `c2`.

In your example `(and integer? positive?)` gives the same result as `positive?`.

Note also that, this implies that `(-> (and integer? positive?) (listof integer?))` works the same as `(-> positive? (listof integer?))`.

In code:

```
(and c1 c2)
```

is the same as

```
(let ([v1 c1])
  (if v1
      (let ([v2 c2])
         v2)
      #f))
```

Since you want a contract that uses both `c1` and `c2` we need a different approach. Let's examine how we can combine two predicates to a simple predicate.

```
(and/p p1 p2)
```

Should be short for

```
(lambda (x)
  (and (p1 x) (p2 x)))
```

Here `and` is used on the values returned by the predicates - not on the predicates themselves.

The construct `and/c` works similar to `and/p` but the representation of contracts is more involved than predicates. The principle is the same though.

is short for

```
(let ([t c1])
  (if t
      t
      c2))
```

Comment: Does and/c pass a boundary?  I get a contract violation with and/c.  I have read the explanation for and/c about 10 times now and I'm still not understanding what it does.

Comment: Sorry! I missed that you used `and` instead of `and/c` in the contract.

Comment: I see that it works with and/c, but... why? Why doesn't it work for and, but it works for and/c?

Comment: Well, `and` works with expressions and `and/c` works with contracts. Hmm. Let's see what happens if we use `and`. In `(and c1 c2)` where `c1` and `c2` evaluates to contracts, since `and` is "short-circuiting" we have that `(and c1 c2)` evaluates to the value of `c1`. The contract `c2` is thusly ignored. The construct `and/c` on the other hand checks  both contracts and checks that both contracts are fulfilled.

Comment: @soegaard `and` should only be able to short-circuit on `#f`, not on `#t`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: You are right. I mixed up c1 and c2. The expression (and c1 c2) will return c2. In your example c2 is positive?

Comment: Good point - but note that the expression `integer?` is a variable reference - not a symbol.

Comment: Sure enough, when I switch the two arguments, I achieve a contract violation, but why is it ignoring c1?

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it was helpful, but the crux of the question is really about the behavior of `and`, not about getting the contract to violate. I still really don't understand why `and` didn't work.

Comment: @Choirbean  I have added a detailed explanation.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it is beautifully explained, though I am still actually confused about one tiny part: When looking at `(and c1 c2)`, why is `c1` necessarily a non-false value, while `c2` can evaluate to false?

Comment: It is non-false if `c1` is a contract such as `integer?` or `positive?` -- remember that `(and integer? ...)` tests whether `integer?` is non-false  -- it doesn't test any values returned by `integer?`.

Comment: But `c2` is a similar boolean statement.  Would `(and c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6)` just be the same as `(and c6)`, with the first contracts always being true, and the last one evaluated as a boolean statement with a return?

Comment: If it is known that c1 to c5 are contracts (and thus non-false values) then yes. If c1 to c6 are arbitrary expressions, then no.

Comment: You must be a saint to still be helping me after all of this time.  I know we typically avoid 'thank-you's on this site, but... you really deserve one. Thank you so very much!